# Converting Epoch Time in String to date field in Impala SQL

Tags: impala, epoch

i have an epoch date time field which is stored as string in database table. i need to cast this to timestamp in impala sql.
I am using the below format and not working.
cast(unix_timestamp(execn_start_ts, "yyyy-MM-dd;HH:mm:ss") as timestamp) where execn_start_ts is the field from my table with unix/epoch time stored as string.

Answer (score 2):

The approach below keeps the ms information if your epoch time ms provides it.

```
select CAST(CAST(ms_epoch_time as BIGINT) / 1000 AS TIMESTAMP)
as new_timestamp
from db.some_tabl_name

--ms_epoch_time - 1608249590791
--new_timestamp -  2020-12-17 23:59:50.790999889
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use
    unix_timestamp(string datetime, string format)

[Impala datetime functions](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html)

Comment: The below worked for me,
SELECT CAST(CAST(execn_start_ts AS BIGINT)/1000 AS TIMESTAMP) as new_timestamp
 FROM table. I got error when i tried unix_timestamp where it said this function cannot have string arguments.

Comment: plz give me your CDH version